# The "advanced search" path returns very wrong results for the `q` parameter

Tags: bug, api-v2, api-v2.2, search, api-v2.1

I'm trying to search for a string. It's a hardware identifier `10ec:8168` and should be unique to that make/model of chip. Any questions that mention is should be relevant.

But compare the site search to the API /search/advanced results:

- **The site**'s: [askubuntu.com/search?q=10ec%3A8168](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=10ec:8168)  **returns 50 questions, and answers**.  All of them are **related to the search string.**
- But **the API**'s: [/2.1/search/advanced?q=10ec%3A8168&site=askubuntu](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=10ec:8168&filter=!9j_cPm*qF&site=askubuntu&run=true) **returns all 113,237 *questions* on the Ubuntu site!**

These two queries should be identical and they're not.
The API's `q` query should return results that are related to the search term.

From [the `/search/advanced` doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search):

> `q` - a free form text parameter, will match all question properties based on an undocumented algorithm.

The API search is crippled.  Please fix the `q` search.  Ideally it should be the same as the site's search.

Comment: Still broken after 2.2 years. :(